# Please translate the following SQL statement

Tags: sql

```
date(dateadd('d',-weekday(currentdate,crMonday),currentdate))+1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What RDMS?  crMonday?  Is this Crystal Reports?

Comment: It seems he is mentally incapable to understood, to what data have other people reach and to what not. Cats are already capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code gives you the first day of the week based on the current date.

`weekday` determines what day of the week it is based on the week starting on a Monday (`crMonday`).  `DateAdd` then subtracts that number of days from the current date.  By adding a day to the result you will get the first day of the week.

```
date(
    dateadd('d',
        -weekday(currentdate,crMonday),
        currentdate)
    )+1
```

**EDIT**: This is the result using today's date. Work from the inner functions to the outer functions.

1. `currentdate = "Tuesday, Oct. 6, 2015"`
2. `-weekday(currentdate, crMonday) = -2`
3. `dateadd('d', -2, currentdate) = "Sunday, Oct. 4, 2015"`
4. `date("04-OCT-2015")+1 = "Monday, Oct. 5, 2015`

Comment: Can you give me an example using today's date

Comment: Edited the answer to show how it calculates.  The result of step 2 will cause step 3 to return the Sunday preceding the current date and then adding a day in step 4 pushes us to Monday (i.e. the first day of the week based on the current date).  `crMonday` means Monday is day 1 and Sunday is day 7 of the week.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.  Not 100% sure it will work since it's "on hold" though.